# Parsing nodes from links in a graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a graph with edges specified in the links array. The function below is parsing the nodes from the links but I don't quite understand how. 
What is the purpose of the first clause in the OR statement , i.e. link.source = nodes[link.source]?

```
var links=[{source:"A", target:"B"}, {source:"B", target:"C"}, {source:"D", target:"E"}, {source:"E", target:"C"}];

var nodes=[];

links.forEach(function(link){
    link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source]={eid:link.source});
    link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target]={eid:link.target});
});
```

I am new to JavaScript and after several attempts of debugging, I'm still lost.

Comment: `nodes[link.source]` is looking for a name in a `nodes` object. Your `nodes` variable is an empty array, which is why you don't get anything from `nodes[link.source]`. For example, on the first pass of your `links.forEach()` loop `link.source == 'A'`, so then it looks for `nodes['A']` and finds nothing. If you had `nodes = {A:"something"}`, then it would return a value. Hopefully that gets you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I meant to ask what is the purpose of having the first clause in the OR condition (link.source = nodes[link.source])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create a `nodes` object by iterating over your `links` array, but you have your `nodes` variable set to an empty array. Instead, you should set it as an empty object: `nodes = {}`. It would make more sense to wrap `links.forEach()` in a function since it seems like the idea would be to call it multiple times and either return the `nodes` object value (if it has been created), or create it if it does not yet exist. Try the example (logging added so you can see the result of the code):

```js
const links = [{ source: "A", target: "B" }, { source: "B", target: "C" }, { source: "D", target: "E" }, { source: "E", target: "C" }];
const nodes = {};  
links.forEach((link) => {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {
    eid: link.source
  });
  
  link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {
    eid: link.target
  });
  
  console.log(link.source);
  console.log(link.target);
});
    
console.log(nodes);
```